# Can't print NULL as null data type when do ->update(" $query ") in laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, single-page-application

I have these actions on my table.

[image]

When click on delete(red icon) it will update the datable called *DeletedDate* from **NULL** to **Date** deleted.
When click on restore(orange icon) iit will update the datable called *DeletedDate* from **Date** deleted to **NULL**.
-VICE VERSA-

In my view I have this code

```
{{ item.DeletedDate == null ? 'mdi-delete-outline' : 'mdi-delete-restore' }}
```

As you can see, the icon will change depend on **item.DeletedDate** value.

I have this code on my **controller.php**

```
//condition
$delete_date = $request->condition == 'delete' ? date('Y/m/d H:i:s') : null;
```

**Query 1**

```
DB::connection('server')->update("
    UPDATE dbo.List
    SET DeletedDate = $delete_date
    WHERE code = '$request->code'
");
```

**Query 2**

```
DB::connection('server')
    ->table('List')
    ->where('code', $request->code)
    ->update([
        'DeletedDate' => $delete_date
]);
```

When I try to do *Query 1*.
It will give errorr *Incorrect syntax near..* So I just add qoute because it prints date.
By changing *SET DeletedDate = $delete_date* to *SET DeletedDate = '$delete_date'*, I can now update value of this *DeletedDate* column without any problem. But...
It gives me error when doing a restore.
I want to remove or change the value of this *DeletedDate* to **NULL** but it just change the value of *DeletedDate* to *1900-01-01 00:00:00.000* when click restore.
It's because it run the query **SET DeletedDate = ''** not **SET DeletedDate = null**

When I do *Query 2*.
I can do **delete** and **restore** without any problem.
And *restore* can change the value of *DeletedDate* to **NULL**.

I wonder why *Query 1* can't print a **null** as NULL data type, But the *Query 2* does.
I tried to use `DB::raw()`, either `DB::statement` can't fix it.

Is there any reason of it?
Thank you for anyone can explain, so I can understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply how PHP works. More specific how strings are evaluated in PHP. It has nothing to do with the database connection or controller logic...

In Query1 you create a *String* , put in *nothing* when inflating the property which means that you are left with an *empty* string (''). There is nothing the controller logic can do to tell whether you actually meant an empty string or a "string representing a `null` value" (which does not exist).

In Query2 you do not hand over a *String* to the controller, but a property that holds the value `null`. That is something the controller logic can handle.

So your issue actually comes from how you create Query1. You'd need to use a ternary operator to get around that behavior of string creation. Something like that:

```
$queryDateValue = $request->code == null ? 'NULL' : $request->code;
DB::connection('server')->update("
    UPDATE dbo.List
    SET DeletedDate = $delete_date
    WHERE code = '$queryDateValue'
");
```

An alternative would be to use a general `convertToLiteralNullIfNull($value)` util function which you can use everywhere.

In general you should avoid to assemble SQL statements by means of String concatenation or inflation, though. They always carry the risk of code injection vulnerabilities. You should always use the combination of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" instead.

---

In a nutshell:

In Query2 you take advantage of the controller logic handling `null` values as neccessary, whereas in Query1 you'd have to do that yourself.

Comment: SET DeletedDate = $delete_date  WHERE code = '$queryDateValue', seriously? When you have full support for prepared statements?

Comment: @YourCommonSense That is indeed an issue, but a completely separate topic. I merely cited the OPs code. Separate topics should be kept separate. Such code does not always mean security issues. It depends on the actual situation.

Comment: This is a public answer you wrote, for the general audience and it should use only best practices, especially in regard this infamous security aspect. Be it a private conversation with the OP, you could write any destructive code you wish. But this is a public post on a site intended to be [a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and your answer is ANYTHING but one.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I added a hint to that issue to the question.

Comment: It's no use to write "hints". It's the code that people come to Stack Overflow for. If you don't know how to write a secure code, you should refrain from answering.

Comment: @YourCommonSense In general I want to add that it is sad to see how aggressive some users get here on SO. That definitely has changed. Once more: whether such implementations are an issue or not is something that can only be decided considering the specific Situation, which we both don't know. Which is why I, personally, tend to concentrate on the question asked. And keep separate topics separate. You are very welcome to act different. But please don't assume you are better than others and have to tell others what to do or not. Thanks.